# Save (override) my jpg file with editing EXIF data

Tags: swift, image, save, jpeg, exif

Im open and edit EXIF (or TIFF...) data in my jpg file.
Please help me save (override) my jpg file with editing data.
Working with this simple code:

```
let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/test/Pictures/IMG_2808.jpg")

if let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(fileURL as CFURL, nil) {
    var imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil) as Dictionary?
    let exifDict = imageProperties?[kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary]

    if let UserComment = exifDict?[kCGImagePropertyExifUserComment] ?? nil {
        print("kCGImagePropertyExifUserComment: \(UserComment)")
    }
    else {
        exifDict!.setValue("My comment...", forKey: kCGImagePropertyExifUserComment as String)
        imageProperties![kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary] = exifDict
        
//      What I should do in the next step for update and override my jpg file on disk?
//      Maybe this is not nice way for this realisation? Please help
//
    }
}
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52810822/saving-exif-data-to-jpeg-swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some test Im found a solution:

```
let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/test/Pictures/IMG_2808.jpg")

if let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(fileURL as CFURL, nil) {
    var imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil) as Dictionary?
    let exifDict = imageProperties?[kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary]

    if let UserComment = exifDict?[kCGImagePropertyExifUserComment] ?? nil {
        print("kCGImagePropertyExifUserComment: \(UserComment)")
    }
    else {
        exifDict!.setValue("My comment...", forKey: kCGImagePropertyExifUserComment as String)
        imageProperties![kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary] = exifDict
     
        if let imageDestination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(fileURL as CFURL, kUTTypeJPEG, 1, nil) {

            CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource(imageDestination, imageSource, 0, imageProperties as CFDictionary?)

            CGImageDestinationFinalize(imageDestination)
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if this solution is true but it works!
Please comment if you know more perfected way